# Does MVC4 membership provider manage tokens for you?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I apologize for what is probably going to end being a dumb question, but I'm somewhat new to custom membership and a lot of the sources on the web only cover SimpleMembership which I'm not interested in. So here's what's going on:

I have a token service that was designed in-house and naturally it is required that we use it. It follows a standard lease token method which is simply:

1. Send it a request for a RequestToken
2. If authentication succeeds, it sends you back a RequestToken
3. You use that request token to request
   a LeaseToken.
4. The service sends you back a lease token which is
   comprised of a token identifier and expiration time
5. The token identifier must be placed into the authorization header for
   subsequent requests

I'm trying to integrate this process into my MVC4 project through the use of a custom provider, but my understanding of it is limited.

I've created a class that inherits from MembershipProvider and auto-implemented all of its abstract members (jeez theres a lot!), and added this class to the providers list in the web.config. I'm assuming what happens is that any time the [Authorize] attribute is encountered, it will run through some process of validating the state of the user's login status.

My question is, does this automatically manage the token that is received during the authentication process? I mean, I don't see how it would out of the box, but I've encountered some things here and there that suggest that MVC *might* have some provisions to support this. Or do I still have to manage the token through the overridden methods in the my Provider?

I imagine that if I still have to write all of this token management, i would simply create all of my necessary classes and logic and then just call it from the appropriate method in the custom membership provider?

These are all assumptions at this stage, so any insight would be helpful. Thanks.